# simplexml_load_file() doesnt display images php

Tags: php, xml

Im retrieving local news from a journal, It has images in the `description` tag, but it doesnt appear in the results. they dont even appear in the code

```
 $feeds = array("https://libero.pe/rss/futbol-peruano");

    //Read each feed's items
    $entries = array();

    foreach($feeds as $feed) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
        $entries = array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath("//item"));

    }
```

HTML

```
         $i=1;
         foreach($entries as $entry){
            if($i<5){
         ?>
         <li><a href="<?= $entry->link ?>"><?= $entry->title ?></a> (<?= parse_url($entry->link)['host'] ?>)
        <p><?= strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', strtotime($entry->pubDate)) ?></p>
        <p><?= $entry->description ?></p></li>
        <?php
        $i++;
       }
       }
```

I was trying to adding `xpath()` whith no success, what Im doing wrong?

```
   foreach( $xml->xpath('//image') as $image)
  {
     $attributes = $image->attributes();
    echo $attributes['path'] . "<br />";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is just whitespace around the content, a simple thing to add is to use `trim()` round the various elements before processing them...

```
 ?>
 <li><a href="<?= trim($entry->link) ?>"><?= trim($entry->title) ?></a> (<?= parse_url(trim($entry->link))['host'] ?>)
<p><?= strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', strtotime(trim($entry->pubDate))) ?></p>
<p><?= trim($entry->description) ?></p></li>
<?php
```

To access the images in the description, you could add an extra loop and use xpath to find the `<img>` entities...

```
foreach ( $entry->description->xpath("descendant::img") as $link )    {
    echo $link['src'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thank you. this is a good point since I wasnt realizing the white spaces in the returned code. I want to retrieve the images from within `description`, the xml url posted is valid and every article has its own set of images...how can I get them?

Comment: Are the images the href of the a tags or something else?

Comment: https://libero.pe/rss/futbol-peruano this is the site feed url. they are `<img src="URL" />` within the `description` tag

Comment: Ive tested, and it returns the whole xml document amount of images within each article description. in other words, every `<li></li>` has 83 images src urls....I need pnly to return the images that belongst to every post. thank you.